# Signature and Timestamp order on a SOAP Header

Tags: .net, vb.net, soap, webservice-client

I’ve been developing a vb.net client that connects to a Webservice using SOAP. This Webservice needs the SOAP message to be signed and have a timestamp.

To this point all is possible, using WSE 2.0 SP3 I’ve able to sign the message and include the Security tag into the SOAP Header and the timestamp tag is included too, as you can see in this sample:

**This is what I send**

```
      <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>http://www.openuri.org/procesa</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>
        uuid:8462973d-f108-4b27-999f-730663978d5b</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
          <wsa:Address>
          http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:To>
        https://serveis-pre.app.aoc.cat/siri-proxy/services/Sincron</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
          <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-05bf25bd-3ca0-4c4a-8052-996353dae4ad">
            <wsu:Created>2011-07-20T10:28:56Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2011-07-20T10:33:56Z</wsu:Expires>
          </wsu:Timestamp>
          <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
          EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
          xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
          wsu:Id="SecurityToken-faacda4d-8c09-4c30-9538-30e95daf674e">      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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
              xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
              <Reference URI="#Id-3ec311d8-8c01-4806-af7e-282a9ae69be7">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>67QHYb7b816b0zisspMyq54mFBU=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue> T7iT+m/JPDCtNVlj72Dj4Mofb/lNIWKLmLf52xuk6A5r1bAW+VH+ZYTbyEBzjLCMt37MiCwT+G6eNiTOfTn59Lxrcmw9ZG2U/1i02EqXA7akNoS+wMk1a9zN28yWDX2QOEEihltnFkJkQksQKI0ZK7/BZLlMFDudaujM2yYdkkA=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-faacda4d-8c09-4c30-9538-30e95daf674e"
                ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
              </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body wsu:Id="Id-3ec311d8-8c01-4806-af7e-282a9ae69be7">
... THE MESSAGE BODY ....
```

The problem is that the Server in which the Webservice is running is configured to recognize a SOAP message in which the signature tag is above the timestamp tag, and by default WSE 2.0 SP3 includes this information on the SOAP Header in the inverse order.

**Order of the tags in my SOAP Message:**

```
<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <Signature>
            <SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <SignatureMethod>
                <Reference>
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
```

**Order in which the server expect the tags to be:**

```
<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <Signature>
            <SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <SignatureMethod>
                <Reference>
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
```

Is there a way to change this order?.

Any suggestions on how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found a way to intercept the creation of the XML string sended to the server.

In order to modify the XML SOAP message before it is sended to the server you have to override the `ProcessMessage` sub on the `Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol` class of your SOAP client.

First you create a new Class that inherits from SoapOutputFilter and overrides the ProcessMessage sub doing what you want to do.

```
Public Class YourOutputFilterClass
    Inherits SoapOutputFilter

    Public Overrides Sub ProcessMessage(ByVal envelope As SoapEnvelope)
        'Find the XmlNode you want to change

        'Change the XmlNode
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then you set your new class as the OutputFilter for your `Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol` Class:

```
Dim YourSOAPClient as New SoapClientClass()
Dim YourOutputFilter as New YourOutputFilterClass()

YourSOAPClient.Pipeline.OutputFilters.Insert(0, YourOutputFilter)
```

With this your OutputFilter will be able to modify the SOAP message before it is sended.